# Convert WSDL1.1 To WSDL2.0

Tags: java, wsdl, ws-security

i am asking how can we convert a WSDL1.1 File that contains some WS-SecurityPolicy to a WSDL2.0 file.

I have tried to use the apache woden framework to do so using this tutorial : http://ssagara.blogspot.com/2009/01/converting-wsdl11-to-wsdl20-using-woden.html, but i'am encountering this problem :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Encountered unknown extension element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy}Policy', as a child of a javax.wsdl.Binding.

coudl any one have a solution for this kind of convertion please ?

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be difficult - since the policy is independent from WSDL. Better remove the security policy from the WSDL 1.1 and convert it to 2.0. Then separately add the policy to the wsdl.

Comment: Thank you for answering ! Well actually my final purpose is to detect the ws-securitypolicy inside any WSDL file (independently if it's a WSDL1.1 or WSDL2.0) using the apache-rampart framework and to do so i have to parse the WSDL file for which i have used wooden framework which parse only the WSDL2.0 files , so if you have any idea to help i would be thankful :)

Answer (score 1):

Woden converter tool based on XSL templates and not support for any extension processing such as WS-Policy. As Prabath mentioned first you need to remove those security policy from WSDL 1.1.

BTW once you add policy to the WSDL 2.0 document Woden can parse them through it's  Extensions handling mechanism. please refer this post http://ssagara.blogspot.com/2009/03/parsing-wsdl-20-extensions-with-woden.html

Comment: Thank you for answering ! actually i have already seen the tutorial in your blog and it was realy helpful for me , but the problem here is that i have to automatically detect any ws-securitypolicy inside any WSDL file (independently if it's a WSDL1.1 or WSDL2.0) so if you have any idea how to do it please send me back ( i sent an email but you did not answer )